# How to pass selected navigation drawer item and Spinner item inside fragment of One activity to second activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I have a navigation drawer in my first activity and upon selection on the navigation drawer I'm going to display a Fragment called SpinnerFragment which has a spinner inside it. I want to pass the selected navigation item and also the selected spinner item to my second activity MainActivity2.java. I'm not adding the xml files, if they are needed to be added please let me know and I will add them.

Can someone please help me how to pass the data of what I selected in the navigation drawer and also in the spinner???

MainActivity.java

```
navigationView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.home_id1:
                    fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.maincontainer,new HomeFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("HomeFragmentYoyo");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                 case  R.id.home_id2:
                    fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.maincontainer,new SpinnerFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Airtel");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                  }//switch case close
            return false;
        }//navigationitemselected close
```

SpinnerFragment.java  (Fragment passed in home_id_2)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v=   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spinner, container, false);
    setSpinnerContent(v);

    Button button=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return  v;
}

private void setSpinnerContent(final View v)
{

    spinner =(Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(v.getContext(),R.array.states_names,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String selected=adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Context context=adapterView.getContext();
            CharSequence text=selected;
            int duration= Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(context,text,duration);
            toast.show();
        }
```

MainActivity2.java

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String m;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I did not read the code itself. When I understand you right, just put the selected item position of the drawer and the position of the selected item in the spinner inside a bundle and pass it over to the next activity where you handle the input.

Comment: Can you write some code how to do that ??

Comment: Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("intKey", 3);
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
intent.putExtra(bundle);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: How to receive the data in the second activity ??